# C# - How to add a SOAP web service reference to my project?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, service

I am attempting to add a web service reference from an example project into my current VS 2015 C# project. This is what I have in the example project:

[image]

To move it over to my new project, I have attempted to copy and paste the "Address" field into my project by right clicking my project and selecting "Add Service Reference". When I do this I get the following error:

```
There was an error downloading 'http://myserver.com/MyServiceExample.svc?wsdl/$metadata'.

The remote name could not be resolved: 'myserver.com'
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://myserver.com/MyServiceExample.svc?wsdl/$metadata'.
There was no endpoint listening at 'http://myserver.com/MyServiceExample.svc?wsdl/$metadata that could accept the message. 

This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.     
See InnerException, if present, for more details.

The remote name could not be resolved: 'myserver.com'
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution    and adding the service reference again.
```

How can I go about adding this service reference into my project? I have tried adding it in by using the VS 2015 CMD Prompt with the `WSDL /verbose` command, but this does not seem to be working. I have the project files and wsdl files for the example, but I cannot get them to work on my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your `web-service` project in `iis express` by launch debug session then when you get temporary url of your service (like http://localhost:8000/MyServiceExample.svc) you can retrive `wsdl` from it.

Just replace `myserver.com` part of url on new one when adding a service reference.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) you can read how adding `service refence` is working but in general you need to retrive contract from deployed `web service` [(wsdl)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) from which `vs` generates new classes.

Later you should change service url in `web.config` on deployed one.

Comment: Your answer got me on the right track. I simply was using the wrong url. Thanks!